# Why do some programs create double indicators on the top panel?

Tags: indicator, jdownloader, hotot

I have several apps that use indicators. Always, when I activate a particular app, Hotot for example, a window and indicator appears on my top panel. If I close the app using the x button, the Hotot window closes and minimizes to the top panel. When I click on Hotot from my Launcher (it is locked on my Launcher) instead of simply opening a window it opens a window *and* another indicator, which doubles the Hotot indicators on my top panel.

Is there a way to stop that? It usually happens with Hotot and JDownloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a problem/bug in those particular applications. When you launch them, they *should* detect that they are running minimized with an indicator, and simply maximize the running instance. But they don't, and instead start a new copy of the program , with indicator and all.

Unless you want to modify the source code yourself, the best way to get this fixed is to file a bug with the respective application's developers.

In the meanwhile, you should try to remember to use the *indicator's menu* to show the app once you have started it, instead of clicking on the Launcher shortcut.